# Do raspberries commonly reseed themselves?

Tags: seedlings, raspberries

Last year, I let the raspberries that had “gone by” just fall off and decompose in the raspberry bed. Now, this year, I see this:

[image]

Among the new primocanes growing from suckers, I see tiny raspberry seedlings that are not connected to any sucker root system.

I am very surprised to see this - I have only ever heard of propagating raspberries by suckers, cane tips rooting, or by planting cuttings from an existing plant. I had therefore assumed that raspberries would not propagate by seed.

My question: is this common to see raspberries reseeding themselves? If I chose to grow a new plant, would it be the same cultivar or is it like apples where it could be anything? If it is relevant, this is the Anne cultivar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do sometimes grow from seed from the fallen fruits. Unfortunately, raspberries do not necessarily come true to the parent plant, so the results of the these seedlings will be variable.